# Function that given these 2 values produces this third value?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that when given 2 arguments, the 2 leftmost columns, produces the third column as a result:

```
0 0 0
1 0 3
2 0 2
3 0 1

0 1 1
1 1 0
2 1 3
3 1 2

0 2 2
1 2 1
2 2 0
3 2 3

0 3 3
1 3 2
2 3 1
3 3 0
```

I know there will be a modulus involved but I can't quite figure it out.

I'm trying to figure out if 4 people are sitting at a table, given the person and target, from the person's perspective which seat is the target sitting in?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that last block of numbers is correct?

Comment: Is the 3rd column of the 4th group correct or should it shift one place (to be 3, 2, 1, 0) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are the positions of the two persons, their "distance" is:

```
(4+b-a) % 4
```

This also shows that the forth block in your example is wrong.

Comment: +1 for the `4` on the LHS, since without it the modulus may be negative (indeed, must be negative in some cases in C99 and C++11).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that last block of numbers is wrong, I think you're looking for (4 + b - a) % 4 gives c (for columns a b c).